# Excel VBA - Counting Specific Values in one Column IF they Match Between Dates

Tags: vba, excel

if anyone could help me, I'd be most grateful. I'm very new to programming and have search tirelessly on the net to find my answer, to no avail.

Basically I have a spreadsheet that contains data of Companies, Items we receive from these companies and the Date we received them e.g.

```
    A         B            C
Company1   Pen         30/05/2016
Company1   Pencil      01/06/2016
Company1   Eraser      01/06/2016
Company1   Marker      30/05/2016
Company2   Paper       02/06/2016
Company2   Card        02/06/2016
Company2   Docket      01/06/2016
Company2   Folder      01/06/2016
Company3   Red Ink     26/05/2016
Company3   Blue Ink    26/05/2016
Company3   Black Ink   28/05/2016
Company3   Printer     28/05/2016
```

Above is an example

My worksheet is called ItemsCompleted

What I need to to count how many times a Company appears between any given two dates.

I have a UserForm with a TextBox (DateFrom), a TextBox (DateTo), a ComboBox (CampanyName), a Button to Execute to the Code and a Label to display the number counted.

```
Worksheets("ItemsCompleted").Select
lblResultsBusCompany = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("D:D"), cmbCompanyResults.Value)
```

This is the code I have to count how many times a particular company work, now I just need the date range bit. That's what I'm really struggling with.

I sincerely hope someone not only understands what I am looking for, but too can assist me.

Thank you in advance.
Jane

Comment: Couldn't you achieve the required result using a pivot table rather than resorting to code?

Comment: I would prefer to use code if I'm honest. I have a UserForm that Users use to input, search and amend data. I would then like to continue to use the form to get some basic stats from it and have it displayed in the label

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to following code, it works once you populate the UserForm objects with the Company's name in the Combo-box, etc. .

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim i                                   As Integer
Dim sht                                 As Worksheet
Dim StartDate, FinishDate               As Date
Dim counter                             As Integer

StartDate = CDate(DateFrom.Text)
FinishDate = CDate(DateTo.Text)

Set sht = Worksheets("ItemsCompleted")

i = 1
counter = 0
While sht.Cells(i, 1) <> ""
    If sht.Cells(i, 1) = CompanyName.Value Then ' compare value of cell with ComboBox value
        If sht.Cells(i, 3) >= StartDate And sht.Cells(i, 3) <= FinishDate Then ' check if column C date is whithin range of selected dates
            counter = counter + 1
        End If
    End If
    i = i + 1
Wend

ResultLabel = counter

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your response, it's very much appreciated.

Unfortunately I can't seem to get the code to work? It keeps coming back as 0 results. I've tried using the same date in From and To dates, and different, all of which I know what he results should show, but as stated it keep coming up as 0.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Jane

Comment: Thank you, the problem was mine and not yours. I strangely had blank cells , which stopped your code from search BEFORE those. It appears to be working well.

Thank you very  much,

Jane

Answer (score 0):

This is inelegant but does the job:

```
t = 0
cn = UserForm1.CompanyName.Value
df = UserForm1.DateFrom.Value
dt = UserForm1.DateTo.Value
lr = ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row
For c = 1 To lr
    If Range("A" & c) = cn And Format(Range("C" & c), "dd/mm/yyyy") >= Format(df, "dd/mm/yyyy") And Format(Range("C" & c), "dd/mm/yyyy") <= Format(dt, "dd/mm/yyyy") Then t = t + 1
Next
UserForm1.lblResultsBusCompany.Caption = Str(t)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your response, it's very much appreciated.

Unfortunately I can only seem to get the code to work if the from and to date are the same, otherwise, if I change the from date, it returns a 0 result. 

 Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Jane